# Is it possible to have nested form (form:form) in spring

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, spring-mvc

Is it possible to have nested form:form in spring mvc?

Comment: No. You just can't. But why you need it?

Answer (score 5):

no, you can you have only one form action/backing object but the backing object could be nested.

Answer (score 3):

It is not possible to have nested forms in HTML.

Spring generates HTML, so it can't have them either.